# Django RetrieveUpdateAPIView not updating

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**I'm using django rest framework.**
I have two models (Model1 and Model2). Each of them has:

- 2 serializers (Model1CreateSerializer, Model1DetailSerializer, Model2CreateSerializer, Model2DetailSerializer). All the serializers extend ModelSerializer.
- 2 views (Model1CreateView Model1DetailView, Model2CreateView, Model2DetailView). All the "...CreateView" extend CreateAPIView and all the "...DetailView" extend **RetrieveUpdateAPIView**

They are very similar.
The first one is working properly: I can create an istance of Model1 using the Model1CreateView and I can see (GET) and patch that istance using the Model1DetailView.
The second one is not working: I can create an istance of Model1 using the Model2CreateView and I can see (GET) that istance using the Model2DetailView. However **I can't manage to update the istance.** No error messages and no update is applied.

I have tried everything. I wrote a new Model, Serializers, Views and table in the database from scratch and it is still not working.
I even reduced the fields and just kept a single Charfield Field in Model2 just to see if a field was the cause of the problem.

Model1

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    Field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Field2 = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    Field3 = models.SmallIntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=3000, blank=True, null=True)
    Field4 = models.SmallIntegerField()
    Field5 = models.ForeignKey('Foreignkey1', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Column1')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'table1'

class Model1DetailView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):

    serializer_class = Model2DetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'model1_id'
    #permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Model1.objects.all()


class Model1CreateView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = Model1CreateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Model1.objects.all()

class Model1CreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5')

class Model1DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5')
        read_only_fields = ('field2')
```

Model2

```
class Model2(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank = True)
    field2 = models.SmallIntegerField()
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=3000, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'table2'

class Model2DetailView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = Model2DetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'model2_id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Model2.objects.all()


class Model2CreateView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = Model2CreateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Model2.objects.all()


class Model2DetailView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):

    serializer_class = Model2DetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'model2_id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Model2.objects.all()


class Model2CreateView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = Model2CreateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Model2.objects.all()
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With Django Rest Framework, you need to use PUT/Patch request and not POST request.